# Using C# XmlDocument, Iterating into the tags of the Complex Xml, and displaying a Value inside inner tag

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I am new to Xml, I have to Iterate into the tags(Loop into all Rack, all Servers, all Model Details, all Power supplies and display the sum of all quantity of all the Power supplies through Pop up message)

I am able to Load the Xml in C# like this:-

```
        XmlDocument xworkload = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".xml"; // Default file extension
            dlg.Filter = "Xml documents (.xml)|*.xml"; // Filter files by extension 

            var result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            if (result == true)
            {
                xworkload.Load(dlg.FileName);
                string xmlcontents = xworkload.InnerXml; // to get xml string, This is working 

                XmlNode xnd =xworkload.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("PowerSupply/quantity");
                foreach(XmlNode _node in xnd)
                {
                  String _nodeValue =_node.InnerText.ToString(); //This is not working
                  MessageBox.Show(_nodeValue.ToString());
                }
            }

       }
```

How to display the Final sum of Power supply Quantity?

Comment: Why `XmlDocument`? Why not LINQ to XML? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is correct XPath you should use:

```
XmlNode xnd = xworkload.SelectSingleNode("//PowerSupply/Item/quantity");
```

You had two problems:

1. `quantity` is not direct child of `PowerSupply` element - there is `Item` between them.
2. Also `PowerSupply` is not direct child of root element, so you need to use `//` to search anywhere in document.

---

Consider also using Linq to Xml for parsing xml. You still able to use XPath:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(dlg.FileName);
int quantity = (int)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//PowerSupply/Item/quantity");
```

That's it - you have integer quantity value in two lines.

**EDIT**: If you have many `PowerSupply` elements and you want to calculate sum of their quantities

```
int sum = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//PowerSupply/Item/quantity")
              .Sum(q => (int)q);
```

Or with your original approach:

```
XmlNodeList quantities = xworkload.SelectNodes("//PowerSupply/Item/quantity");
int sum = 0;
foreach (XmlNode quantity in quantities)
    sum += Int32.Parse(quantity.InnerText);
```

Comment: The `.DocumentElement` portion is unnecessary.

Comment: @JLRishe agree, that's unnecessary, but there is nothing wrong in usage it

Comment: You also shouldn't be using `SelectSingleNode` for this. That will select at most one power supply quantity, and the next line will fail with a NullReferenceException if there are none.

Comment: @JLRishe I believe we should know what data contained in all xml documents to make such assumptions. Currently I see only one `PowerSupply` element, and OP was using `SelectSingleNode` with wrong xpath. If it is possible that no `PowerSupply` elements will be in xml (we don't know that) simple null-check will solve NullReferenceException problem. What is redundant here is a `foreach` loop I thinkg

Comment: _"I have to Load this Xml using XmlDocument in C# and then Iterate into the tags(Loop into ... all Power supplies and display the quantity of the Power supply through Pop up message)"_

Comment: I have to iterate through all the tags and retrieve the sum of quantities of Power supply in the Xml.

Comment: @MishraSaurabh OK, updates answer (I also added Linq to Xml sample, which is more proffered way for xml parsing)

Comment: Thanks @SergeyBerezovskiy, It was a great help !!!    MessageBox.Show("The sum of power supply Quantity is " + sum); will display the sum.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `.SelectNodes` and an `XmlNodeList`. Also, the `.DocumentElement` part is extraneous and unnecessary, and there was an issue with your XPath.

There's also no need to call `.ToString()` on a string and then call it again on *that* string:

```
XmlNodeList xnd = xworkload.SelectNodes("//PowerSupply/Item/quantity");
foreach(XmlNode _node in xnd)
{
  string _nodeValue =_node.InnerText;
  MessageBox.Show(_nodeValue);
}
```

You could get the total quantity of power supplies like this:

```
XmlNodeList xnd = xworkload.SelectNodes("//PowerSupply/Item/quantity");
int powerSupplyCount = 0;
foreach(XmlNode _node in xnd)
{
  int count;
  if(int.TryParse(_node.InnerText, out count)) 
  {
      powerSupplyCount += count;
  }
}

MessageBox.Show(powerSupplyCount.ToString());
```

Comment: -It gives Error, The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(string) has some invalid arguments'

Comment: I've shown you how to correctly iterate through the Power Supply quantities and total them. You should be able to extrapolate this to figure out the rest, but if you really can't, I suggest opening another question for that part.